# Oracle Apex - How can I use dynamic actions to update List of Values on change action?

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle-apex

I am looking for someone familiar with Oracle Apex who could help me solve this problem. I'm trying to cause my LOV to update itself (in a form) after I pick a specific date from datepicker. I have a working LOV - checked it by setting default value of the date field which caused expected behavior of my LOV. I tried searching for solutions but the only one I found don't really do anything - '''$('#skladka_form').trigger('apexrefresh');''' (Execute Javascript Code). Will be very grateful for any tips. Feel free to ask any questions if you didn't get the problem.

Answer (score 4):

APEX is a "low code" development tool, which minimises the need to code your own solutions to requirements.  In this case all you need is a "cascading LOV".  I'll use a form based on the classic Oracle EMP (employees) table as an example.  We'll have 2 items:

- P2_DATE - a datepicker item
- P2_EMPNO - a select list based on the EMP table

The (contrived) twist is that P2_DATE is the "minimum hire date", so we only want the select list to show employees hired on or after that date.

[image]

The query I have used for the LOV is:

```
select ename, empno
from emp
where hiredate >= to_date(:P2_DATE)
order by 1;
```

Now, all I have to do to make the LOV refresh whenever P2_DATE is changed is set this property on P2_EMPNO:

[image]

That's it, job done!

You can run my page yourself [here on apex.oracle.com](https://apex.oracle.com/pls/apex/f?p=124768:2).  There is a list of employees and their hire dates on the right to help you pick suitable dates.

Comment: Thank you very much. It seems that it is what I've been looking for. Great and simple solution. :)

Comment: Why didn't you accept/upvote the answer, then, @Raz?

Comment: I did but to be honest this is my first account-based activity on stackoverflow, because so far I didn't need to look for help by asking a question myself - my upvote doesn't count towards the score you see by the standards of stackoverflow.